# Type Inference in Haskell for functions

Tags: haskell

I am doing practice problems for Haskell and one of the problems is

```
test3 x y = x (x y)
```

for which I have to find the type.

The solution is

```
test3 :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

I am not understanding why the variables in the solution are all a's instead of referring to x and y as two different variables like a and b. Could someone explain that and also go through how to find the type of this problem.

Comment: The type of both x and y are not the same.  Could you please explain what type you think `x` has and what type you think `y` has and why you think the type of `test3` says they are the same?

Comment: Sorry to clarify I mean why in the solution are all the variables are a like for example shouldn't the third a in the solution be a b since it refers to the type of y?

Comment: The key insight is that `x` is applied to both `y` and `x y`, which means the argument type and the return type of `x` have to be the same.

Comment: @raytoal csj Said `x` and `y` have the same type, this indicates either sloppy phrasing or a misunderstanding so I asked for a clarification.  The type of `x` is a function `a -> a` where as the type of `y` need not be, it is unrestrained `y :: a`.  Ah, a misunderstanding as is common in short text communication - no worries.

Comment: Got it, my bad.

Answer (score 20):

This is quite an interesting exercise, actually. It doesn't require any Haskell-specific knowledge - it's really just basic logic.

```
test3 x y = x (x y)
```

The first thing to note is that `test3` takes 2 arguments (the `x` and `y`) and produces some kind of result. So the type must be of the form

```
a -> b -> c
```

and it only remains to figure out what `a`, `b` and `c` are, or at least what relations exist between them.

So let's examine that result `x (x y)` in more detail. It tells us that `x` is a function which can take `y` as an argument. We have said that `y` has type `b` (which is a completely arbitrary name, but let's stick with it for now) - so `x` must be a function which takes a `b` and produces a result of some type. Let's call that type `d` for now. So we know that the type of `test3` is of the form

```
(b -> d) -> b -> c
```

Finally, again from the expression `x (x y)`, we see that `x` must take the `x y` - which we've assigned the type `d` - and return a result. And this result is the overall result of `test3`, whose type we've chosen to call `c`. So, in the above, `x` - to which we've already assigned the type `b -> d`, must have type `d -> c`. The only way `b -> d` can be equal to `d -> c` is if `b`, `c` and `d` are all the same type. (Because the types of functions are determine by their input type and result type.) So the overall type of `test3` must be of the form

```
(b -> b) -> b -> b
```

Which is exactly what you've been told it is - up to a renaming of `a` to `b`. (The names are, as I said, arbitrary anyway - so it's not relevant.)